# Firebase Phone Auth failed to sign out flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have tried all the methods to sign out from firebase auth. I am using Phone number auth in the Flutter app using Firebase but am unable to sign out the user. Every time I restart the app it leads me to the Home page but when I click the Logout button it takes me to the Login page.
What I want is a simple sign-out.

Authentication class

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_express/pages/login_signup/login.dart';

class Authentication{
  Future<void> logOut(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) => {
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()), (route) => false)
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e); // TODO: show dialog with error
    }
  }
}
```

Profile Widget

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_express/constant/constant.dart';
import 'package:food_express/functions/Authentication.dart';
import 'package:food_express/pages/login_signup/login.dart';
import 'package:food_express/pages/order/history_order/history.dart';
import 'package:food_express/pages/order/order.dart';
import 'package:food_express/pages/profile/edit_profile.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';
import 'package:food_express/pages/profile/address.dart';
import 'package:food_express/pages/notification.dart';
import "../../constant/globals.dart" as global;

class Profile extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    logoutDialogue() {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          // return object of type Dialog
          return Dialog(
            elevation: 0.0,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
            child: Container(
              height: 130.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "You sure want to logout?",
                    style: headingStyle,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          logout(context);
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          width: (width / 3.5),
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey[300],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            'Cancel',
                            style: buttonBlackTextStyle,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          width: (width / 3.5),
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: primaryColor,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            'Log out',
                            style: wbuttonWhiteTextStyle,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: scaffoldBgColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: whiteColor,
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text(
          'Profile',
          style: bigHeadingStyle,
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  PageTransition(
                      type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                      child: EditProfile()));
            },
            child: Container(
              width: width,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(fixPadding),
              color: whiteColor,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 70.0,
                        height: 70.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(
                                "https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20200224/original/pngtree-cartoon-color-simple-male-avatar-png-image_5230557.jpg"),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      widthSpace,
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            global.profile.Name.toString(),
                            style: headingStyle,
                          ),
                          heightSpace,
                          Text(
                            global.profile.PhoneNumber.toString(),
                            style: lightGreyStyle,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                    size: 16.0,
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(fixPadding),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(fixPadding),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: whiteColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                BoxShadow(
                  blurRadius: 1.5,
                  spreadRadius: 1.5,
                  color: Colors.grey[200],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        PageTransition(
                            type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                            child: Notifications()));
                  },
                  child: getTile(
                      Icon(Icons.notifications,
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6)),
                      'Notifications'),
                ),
                /* InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft, child: PaymentMethods()));
                  },
                  child: getTile(
                      Icon(Icons.payment, color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6)),
                      'Payment Methods'),
                ),

                */

                /*InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: getTile(
                      Icon(Icons.local_activity,
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6)),
                      'My Vouchers'),
                ),

                 */

                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: getTile(
                      Icon(Icons.group_add,
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6)),
                      'Invite Friends'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(fixPadding),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(fixPadding),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: whiteColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                BoxShadow(
                  blurRadius: 1.5,
                  spreadRadius: 1.5,
                  color: Colors.grey[200],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        PageTransition(
                            type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                            child: Order()));
                  },
                  child: getTile(
                      Icon(Icons.history, color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6)),
                      'Order History'),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: getTile(
                      Icon(Icons.group, color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6)),
                      'Become our partner'),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: getTile(
                      Icon(Icons.headset_mic,
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6)),
                      'Support'),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: getTile(
                      Icon(Icons.star_rate,
                          color: Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.6)),
                      'Rate our App'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(fixPadding),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(fixPadding),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: whiteColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                BoxShadow(
                  blurRadius: 1.5,
                  spreadRadius: 1.5,
                  color: Colors.grey[200],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                InkWell(
                  onTap: logoutDialogue,
                  child: getTile(
                      Icon(Icons.exit_to_app,
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6)),
                      'Logout'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  getTile(Icon icon, String title) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 40.0,
              width: 40.0,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: icon,
            ),
            widthSpace,
            Text(
              title,
              style: listItemTitleStyle,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
          size: 16.0,
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void logout(context) {
    Authentication _auth = Authentication();
    _auth.logOut(context);
    // await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    // Navigator.pop(context);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what behavior you want. In the code you posted there is no reference to you checking for the authentication state changes inside your app. Where is the control that the app performs to check if a user is authenticated?

Comment: Authentication is checked before using a method Home but the problem is this logout button is not signing out the user from the app. Just navigating the user to the login page as it had logged out the user from the app but when I restart the app takes me to the home.. Everything is working fine but the user is not signing out that's my issue I had read all the necessary articles and posts regarding sign out but failed to resolve this problem

Comment: I'm guessing: since the log out isn't throwing any exception, maybe is the check at the beginning that has something that doesn't work properly.

Comment: I am printing the User uid on login screen just to check whether user logged out or not but every time I signing out its printing UID therefore if Signout would have worked correctly it should not be printing uid.

Comment: Thank you for your help you was a mistake in my code. I was calling signout on cancel button but pressing an ok button thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Check the current user already log or not when log out, and when you use then block, you don't need to use the await keyword.

```
Future<void> logOut(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      final User firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
       
      if (firebaseUser != null) {
          FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) => {
            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) 
            => Login()), (route) => false)
          });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e); // TODO: show dialog with error
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my code but the code you posted here had an issue firebase user cannot be assigned to the variable without await since its a future function anyways thank you for your help :)

Comment: is the rest of the code works and solved your problem?